# pthread_create swift sample

Tags: swift, pthreads

Due to I need to port an application from C to Swift I would like to know if there is any sample about using pthread_create, and pthread_join on Swift. I know that usually we have to use NSThreads or the GCD but in this case I need to keep the application code the closest possible to the C application.
Can anyone put an example here?
By the way, the function to be called is a Swift function, not a C function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faced the problem too. Here is short sample below. Hope it help someone further:

**Swift 4**

```
class ThreadContext {

    var someValue: String = "Some value"
}

func doSomething(pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer? {

    let pContext = pointer.bindMemory(to: ThreadContext.self, capacity: 1)
    print("Hello world: \(pContext.pointee.someValue)")

    return nil
}

var attibutes = UnsafeMutablePointer<pthread_attr_t>.allocate(capacity: 1)
guard 0 == pthread_attr_init(attibutes) else {

    fatalError("unable to initialize attributes")
}

defer {

    pthread_attr_destroy(attibutes)
}

guard 0 == pthread_attr_setdetachstate(attibutes, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE) else {

    fatalError("unable to set detach state")
}

let pContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<ThreadContext>.allocate(capacity: 1)
var context = ThreadContext()
pContext.pointee = context

var thread: pthread_t? = nil
let result = pthread_create(&thread, attibutes, doSomething, pContext)

guard result == 0, let thread = thread else {

    fatalError("unable to start pthread")
}

pthread_join(thread, nil)
```

Comment: Where is pthread_attr_t and the rest of stuff declared? Do I have to create a bridge file?

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad nope you don’t need doing any bridging stuff. Just import foundation - that’ enough

Comment: It might be new. When I asked this question was when Swift 1 was released. At that time I think that these functions weren't available. I'm glad that now it is possible doing it.

Comment: Was this compiling on a 32-bit system? This doesn't compile on 64-bit systems with errors like "cannot convert `Int` to expected argument of type `Int32`.